# How can I move around the bash commandline efficiently?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bash

So I use the <kbd>up</kbd> in my shell (Bash on OSX or Ubuntu, mostly) but some of the time I know that I want the stuff *after* the cursor's current location. Is there any way to have the line I'm on **complete** with the line above? Hitting <kbd>up</kbd> and then <kbd>left</kbd> is annoying.

Any other tricks would be cool too, except for <kbd>tab</kbd>, which we all now about :)

**Here's an example (per ~quack's request):**

I type `mkdir /where/the/hell/is/that/thing` and then I want to cd into the same directory. But now I know about meta-b :)

Comment: an explicit example would be awesome.

Comment: @~quack doing example now

Comment: here's a related (duplicated) question, with a quite nice answer: http://superuser.com/questions/124336/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts-for-terminal/124367#124367

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
mkdir /where/the/hell/is/that/thing
```

then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

depending on your OS and terminal you might have to type
    <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>.</kbd>

You can also press     <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to pick a specific prior argument.

This is much better than !! or !$ because you can actually see what you are about to run, and it takes less keystrokes anyway.

edit: strictly speaking it is <kbd>meta</kbd> not <kbd>alt</kbd>, so it might also work with the "windows" key depending on how your keyboard is setup..

Comment: interesting! didn't know about that one.

Comment: @justin this is awesome. On OSX meta is escape.

Comment: @yar with OS X Terminal there is also a preference setting under 'Settings' -> 'Keyboard' to 'use option as meta key'.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasW I gotta get back to this stuff. I'm on the command line daily, but use very little of the tricks.

Answer (score 29):

You should read through [*man bash*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) on your system, particularly the section on **Readline**, as this is bash's interactive input mechanism.  The [Bash manual at gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) has a nice section on [Commandline Editing](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing) that will help fill in some of the gaps.

By default, you can use these to [move around](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Movement-Commands) on the commandline (just listing a few here; see the link for a full list):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> moves to the beginning of the line (or <kbd>Home</kbd> depending on terminal settings)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> moves to the end of the line (or <kbd>End</kbd> ...)
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> moves forward a "word"
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> moves backward a "word"

You can use these to ["kill" (aka "cut") text](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Killing-Commands) from a line:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> kills ("cuts") text from the current cursor position to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> yanks ("pastes") the most recently killed text back into the buffer at the cursor

So you can combine these to select a chunk of some commandline you want to repeat, kill it, then paste it to the end of your next command.

---

Now, to make it even more fun, let's consider bash's [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).  This is that `!!` that [Studer's answer mentions](https://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently/113119#113119).  History expansion breaks down into [*event designators*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators), [*word designators*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators), and [*modifiers*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Modifiers).

*Event* designators look like this (again, see the links for the full list):

- `!` - starts a history substitution
- `!n` - the *n-th* command in bash's history list, for some integer *n* (works for negatives too)
- `!!` - the preceeding command; equivalent to `!-1`
- `!string` - the most recent command starting with *string*

*Word* designators select certain parts from an event.  Use `:` to separate the event from the word designator.  Words are numbered from 0 starting at the beginning of the line, and inserted into the current line separated by single spaces.

- `$` - designates the last argument (eg `!!:$` is the last arg of last command; can be shortened to `!$`)
- `n` - designates the *n-th* word (eg `!str:2` is the 2nd arg of the most recent command starting with *str*; `!!:0` is the *command* of the last command)

So, to follow up on your example, if your last command is `mkdir /some/really/long/path`, just running `!!` will rerun that command again.  But you want to `cd` into that path instead:

```
$ cd !$
```

Now let's say you perform some other commands and then want to refer back to that path again.  If that was the last *mkdir* command you ran, you can use this to repeat that path:

```
$ tar czf ~/foo.tgz !mkdir:$
```

Comment: you can also *bind* these (and other Readline commands) to whatever key combinations you like; see section 8.4 of the manual, Bindable Readline Commands: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands and section 8.3, Readline Init File: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File

Comment: thanks that really helps. Although "read the manual" was kind of expected, mentioning the basic moving around bindings does help. Even just knowing ctrl-a might be  real savings.

Comment: @quack, no problem, I caught a later revision, in fact :)

Comment: also note `bind -p` or `bind -P` will print your current keybindings; that's the ultimate reference for what your *bash* uses.

Comment: I think this answer has grown: the stuff on History Expansion is great.

Comment: @quack quixote Where is the *Meta* Key or does it have some implicit meaning that I am missing here?

Comment: @Geek Meta key depends on OS and shell. With bash on MacOS, it apparently is ESC, which is also what I see when I run `man bash` and skip to "READLINE". Fair warning: it's not working for me either, and the only help I've found so far is people asking how to re-assign Meta to Option (which I don't want; I just want Esc to actually work).

Answer (score 6):

If you're a vi user you can put the shell into vi mode by typing `set -o vi`.

You can then do all kinds of powerful things on the command line after typing `Esc + k`.

The one I use the most is `Esc+K` then `/` any text typed after the slash will be used to search through your command line history.

e.g. `Esc + k` `/smbclient`
will give the last smbclient command you typed.  You can scroll through all the searches using standard vi keys (`j` and `k` for up and down but I think up and down arrows will work too).

Further help [here](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#vi), there are also some inbuilt bash things at that link which might be more what you're looking for.

Cheers,
  Stu.

Comment: while vi mode is useless to me, since I haven't yet stepped up to vi, the l ink is awesome. Thanks for that!

Comment: The equivalent without vi mode is ctrl-r. Type it, and then part of a previous command. It will bring up the last occurrence of what was typed. Hit ctrl-r again to get to the next one. Very handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `!!` which represents the last command :

```
% test
% echo !!
> test
```

Comment: interesting. Not sure that I want to then manipulate that string using...what?

Comment: this is part of bash's history facilities: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively .. particularly the history expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction ... note `!!` is a synonym for `!-1`: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators

Comment: This is really useful for when you forget to use sudo: i.e. sudo !!
--
$ more /etc/sudoers
/etc/sudoers: Permission denied
$ sudo !!
sudo more /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for ..:
# /etc/sudoers
...
...
...

Comment: @wookiebreath, thanks for that, I'll vote this answer up now

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, use !$ to represent the last parameter of the previous command:

> mkdir /something/somethingelse
>
> cd !$

You can also use numbered variations to pull out specific parameters of previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [this readline cheat-sheet](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) very useful. Lots of things I didn't know. I used to use `!$` all the time until I found out about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, which I now use all the time. :)