# How to go back or forward a word in bash environment?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move around the bash commandline efficiently?](https://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently)

In the Windows prompt, one can go back or forward one word by pressing `ctrl` and `<-/->`. What's the equivalent in a bash environment?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently/113117#113117

Answer (score 32):

There is `M-b` and `M-f` for moving backwards and forwards to the current word, respectively. Here `M` is the <kbd>Meta</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or a combination, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>. The section [Commands for Moving](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Movement-Commands) in the `bash` manpage lists these and other shortcuts available for moving on the bash shell.

The manual also describes how to customize your bash settings so you can use your known <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to skip words.

Comment: I tried `Esc+b/f`,not working .

Comment: Try the `Alt` key as well. The meta key is also emulated with the `alt` or `windows` key on keyboards that have them.

Comment: @user11671: Does `bind -p|grep forward-word` produce `"\ef": forward-word` (among other things)?

Comment: `Alt + Shift` is the meta key on my Gnome terminal.

Comment: To directly answer the user's question, this works for me in ~/.inputrc in Ubuntu:

# Assign Ctrl-right-arrow and Ctrl-left-arrow move to next/previous word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=35154

Comment: Is there a way to navigate words as whitespace-delimited sequences of characters, and not as sequences of alphabetical characters?

Comment: @dougkramer how does that directly answer users question? that's about rebinding the command, whereas user is asking what is the default equivalent