# Is there any way to undo edition of command in Linux (Ubuntu) terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there any way to undo edition of command in terminal? E.g. I have a long string which I edited before running a command, and I want to undo some of those edits before pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you activate vi or emacs mode (`set -o emacs` or `set -o vi` ) you can use many advanced features like 'undo'. The default is emacs mode, so ctrl-_ should already do an undo.

Comment: +1.  as this is handled by bash's Readline facility, the OP might be interested in this answer that provides some of the basics of bash shortcuts: http://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently/113117#113117 .. another answer to that question provides this link for bash's vi mode: http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#vi