# Delete until previous punctuation mark in Bash

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, bash

In Bash, Ctrl + W will erase the last word.  Bash considers words to be delimited by spaces.

This means that if the cursor is at the end of the string "cd /dir1/dir2/dir3" and you hit Ctrl + W you will be left with "cd ".

Is there a Bash shortcut (custom defined is okay) that will leave me with "cd /dir1/dir2/"?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently .. also see questions listed at http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash+keyboard-shortcuts .. do any of those answer your question?

Comment: note with standard bash keys, you can do this with Meta+B then Ctrl+K (move-backward-word then cut-to-end-of-line); from http://superuser.com/questions/113103/how-can-i-move-around-the-bash-commandline-efficiently/113117#113117

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258661/46465 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/409671/157603 helped me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) which should be bound to `backward-kill-word` (and you could bind to something else).

Comment: Meta + Backspace does the same too.